# JavaScript load command

Tags: javascript, html, load

I'm looking through some code from GitHub and I can't seem to figure out why this line of code is there, nor can I find anything about it online.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
```

What does "load" do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: `load` is an event. See  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#read-html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: @roshan: I don't think the OP want's to build a Firefox add-on.

Comment: a quick google of "window load" returns all the information i could ever need.... try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 0):

The window.onload event is used to kick-start web applications. This could be something trivial like animating a menu or something complex like initializing a mail application.

The onload event fires after all page content has loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

also look at the following link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load